# How to compensate translate when skewX and skewY are used on SVG

Tags: javascript, math, svg, transform, skew

**CONTEXT**: @AnaTudor (@daredevil) [is talking about](https://css-tricks.com/transforms-on-svg-elements/#article-header-id-4) the `d` distance of movement for SVGs when `skewX` or `skewY` are used, so I was wondering if there is any way to calculate that distance in order to compensate with translate, and avoid using chained `translate`.

**Test case**: In the below snipet, we WON'T USE SVG specific chaining and/or nesting, we ONLY use same transform values, but in specific order of transform functions;

- *LEFT green rectangle* via `style`: `translate`, `rotate`, `skewX`, `skewY`, `scale`;
- *RIGHT olive rectangle* via `transform` attribute: `translate`, `scale`, `rotate`, `skewX`, `skewY.

Now, as you can see, the two rectangles have different positioning, if you click the button, the second rectangle gonna get closer to what we would expect, but still need to compute more for all cases.

**Question**: how can we change the `fixOrigin` function to adjust the translation for all possible transform function combinations, in a way that looks same as the CSS3 transform?

```js
var el1 = document.querySelectorAll('path')[0],
    el2 = document.querySelectorAll('path')[1],
    el2BB = el2.getBBox(), el2cx = el2BB.x + el2BB.width/2, el2cy = el2BB.y + el2BB.height/2,
    btn = document.querySelectorAll('button')[0], btn1 = document.querySelectorAll('button')[1],
    x = 20, y = 20, scale = 0.6, rotate = 45, skewX = 20, skewY = -20;


el1.style.transform = 'translate(20px, 20px) rotate(45deg) skewX(20deg) skewY(-20deg) scale(0.6)';
el1.style.transformOrigin = '50% 50% 0px';

el2.setAttribute('transform', 'translate('+x+','+y+') scale('+scale+') rotate('+rotate+' '+el2cx+','+el2cy+') skewX('+skewX+') skewY('+skewY+')');

function fixOrigin(){
  x += (1-scale) * el2BB.width/2;
  y += (1-scale) * el2BB.height/2;
  el2.setAttribute('transform', 'translate('+x+','+y+') scale('+scale+') rotate('+rotate+' '+el2cx+','+el2cy+') skewX('+skewX+') skewY('+skewY+')');
}
btn.addEventListener('click',fixOrigin,false);

function fixEverything() {
  // scale binds all transform functions together
  if ( !!scale ) {
    //most important make sure we have translation values
    //!!(x) && (x=0); !!(y) && (y=0);
    
    // first adjust translate based on scale value
    x += (1-scale) * el2BB.width/2;
    y += (1-scale) * el2BB.height/2;
      
    //now we also adjust the rotation transform  origin based on SKEWS
    if (!!rotate) {
      // el2cx += .... el2cy += ...
    }
    
    //almost there, now we adjust the translation based on SKEWS
    // x += ... y += ...
  
  // last case, when SKEWS are used alone
  } else if ( !scale && !rotate ) {
    // adjust translation here
    // x += ... y += ...
  }

  el2.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(' + x + ',' + y + ') scale(' + scale + ') rotate(' + rotate + ' ' + el2cx + ',' + el2cy + ') skewX(' + skewX + ') skewY(' + skewY + ')');
}

btn1.addEventListener('click', fixEverything, false);
```

```css
/* desired transform
transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px; 
transform: translate(20px, 20px) rotate(45deg) skewX(20deg) skewY(-20deg) scale(0.6);
*/

svg {
  overflow: visible; width:30%;
  border: 1px solid #eee; /* some sort of ruler */
}
```

```html
<button>Fix Transform Origin</button><button>Fix All</button><br>
<p>Click to change the `transform` attribute</p>
<svg id="svgMixedCSS" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 600 500">
    <path fill="green" d="M426.671 0h-341.328c-46.937 0-85.343 38.405-85.343 85.345v341.311c0 46.969 38.406 85.344 85.343 85.344h341.328c46.938 0 85.329-38.375 85.329-85.345v-341.31c0-46.94-38.391-85.345-85.329-85.345z" ></path>
</svg>
<svg id="svgMixedAttr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 600 500">  
  <path fill="indigo" d="M426.671 0h-341.328c-46.937 0-85.343 38.405-85.343 85.345v341.311c0 46.969 38.406 85.344 85.343 85.344h341.328c46.938 0 85.329-38.375 85.329-85.345v-341.31c0-46.94-38.391-85.345-85.329-85.345z"></path>            
</svg>
```

I made a super cool snipet for you to play around. UPDATE: Also it has a function draft with all possible cases.

Comment: It is kind of hard to understand what you're actually asking without reading the linked article in great detail. Would I be correct to assume that you essentially want to understand how to transform a `skewX(c) translate(a, b)` into a `translate(d, e) skewX(c)` which does exactly the same? And then you can move the outer `translate` to the `viewBox`?

Comment: No need indeed. But I figured a formula. I was playing with http://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1272730391 and came with an idea: using the `getBBox()` I can calculate the perimeter of the shape's outer-box (let's say a circle) with and without the skew, then half difference of 2 perimeters should be exactly the `d` value. Man I was good at math in school :P

Comment: Even better, this thing calculates everything
http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/geometry-plane/parallelogram.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your edited question and the example it contains makes it clearer that what you are *really* after is translate CSS3 `style="transform: …"` transformations into equivalent SVG `transform="…"` transformations. In particular in a way which allows for the CSS3 `transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px` which places the center of transformation at the center of the object, as opposed to the origin of the SVG coordinate system.

The snippet below demonstrates two ways to achieve this. One is fairly simple: First translate the center of the object (which you already computed in the snippet from your question) to the origin, then perform all the transformations, then translate the point back to its original coordinates. That's the object in the center, which has essentially

```
transform="translate(256,256)
           translate(20, 20)
           rotate(45) skewX(20) skewY(-20) scale(0.6)
           translate(-256,-256)"
```

But in your question you wrote that you'd like to “avoid using chained `translate`”, which the above makes use of (in a sense). In order to avoid that, you can combine all the translate steps into one. The code below does that, moving translate steps to the outside i.e. to the beginning of the sequence. The end result is essentially

```
transform="translate(211.325,73.165)
           rotate(45) skewX(20) skewY(-20) scale(0.6)"
```

except for the actual result having more digits for each of these numbers. Personally I think that the first approach is easier and cleaner, but the second is probably closer to what you had in mind.

One particular benefit is that the code iterates over the elementary transformations in the order in which they are given in the transformation description, so that users are free to give transformations in any order they like, and the translations can still get collected appropriately.

```js
var el1 = document.querySelectorAll('path')[0],
    el2 = document.querySelectorAll('path')[1],
    el2BB = el2.getBBox(), el2cx = el2BB.x + el2BB.width/2, el2cy = el2BB.y + el2BB.height/2,
    el3 = document.querySelectorAll('path')[2],
    transform = 'translate(20px, 20px) rotate(45deg) skewX(20deg) skewY(-20deg) scale(0.6)';


el1.style.transform = transform;
el1.style.transformOrigin = '50% 50% 0px';

transform = 'translate('+el2cx+','+el2cy+') ' + transform.replace(/deg/g,'').replace(/px/g,'')+' translate('+(-el2cx)+','+(-el2cy)+')';
el2.setAttribute('transform', transform);

el3.setAttribute('transform', combineTranslates(transform));

function combineTranslates(transform) {
    var ts = [], // will contain list of elementary transformations
        r = /\s*([A-Za-z0-9]+\s*\([\-0-9.,\s]*\))/g,
        match,
        pos = 0, // used during tokenization
        deg = Math.PI/180.0,
        x = 0, y = 0, // translation gets accumulated here
        tmp;

    // Tokenize transform into individual elementary transformations
    while (match = r.exec(transform)) {
        if (match.index !== pos) throw Error('Invalid transform: ' + transform);
        pos += match[0].length;
        ts.push(match[1]);
    }
    // TODO: check that only whitespace remains after matches
    //console.log(ts);

    // Iterate over transformations from inside to outside
    for (var i = ts.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        match = /([A-Za-z0-9]+)\s*\(([\-0-9.,\s]*)\)/.exec(ts[i]);
        var op = match[1],
            args = match[2].replace(/\s+/g, '').split(',').map(Number);
        //console.log(op, args);
        switch (op) {
            // Apply given transformation to (x,y) vector
            case 'translate':
                x += args[0];
                y += args[1];
                ts.splice(i, 1); // Drop translate from ts array
                break;
            case 'rotate':
                var angle = args[0]*deg,
                    cos = Math.cos(angle),
                    sin = Math.sin(angle);
                tmp = cos*x - sin*y;
                y = sin*x + cos*y;
                x = tmp;
                break;
            case 'scale':
                x *= args[0];
                y *= (args.length === 1 ? args[0] : args[1]);
                break;
            case 'skewX':
                x += y*Math.tan(args[0]*deg);
                break;
            case 'skewY':
                y += x*Math.tan(args[0]*deg);
                break;
            default:
                throw Error('Unknown transform ' + op)
        }
    }
    ts.unshift('translate('+x+','+y+')'); // add as first element
    //console.log('From '+transform+'\n  to '+ts.join(' '));
    return ts.join(' ');
};
```

```css
svg { overflow: visible; width:30%; border: 1px solid #eee; }
```

```html
<svg id="svgMixedCSS" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 600 500">
    <path fill="green" d="M426.671 0h-341.328c-46.937 0-85.343 38.405-85.343 85.345v341.311c0 46.969 38.406 85.344 85.343 85.344h341.328c46.938 0 85.329-38.375 85.329-85.345v-341.31c0-46.94-38.391-85.345-85.329-85.345z" ></path>
</svg>
<svg id="svgMixedAttr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 600 500">  
  <path fill="indigo" d="M426.671 0h-341.328c-46.937 0-85.343 38.405-85.343 85.345v341.311c0 46.969 38.406 85.344 85.343 85.344h341.328c46.938 0 85.329-38.375 85.329-85.345v-341.31c0-46.94-38.391-85.345-85.329-85.345z"></path>            
</svg>
<svg id="svgCombinedAttr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 600 500">  
  <path fill="blue" d="M426.671 0h-341.328c-46.937 0-85.343 38.405-85.343 85.345v341.311c0 46.969 38.406 85.344 85.343 85.344h341.328c46.938 0 85.329-38.375 85.329-85.345v-341.31c0-46.94-38.391-85.345-85.329-85.345z"></path>            
</svg>
```

Comment: thanks a million for your time, it's true I was after equivalent transforms for SVG. Yesterday I was thinking finding the `d` would be a good start, probably the final resolve, I absolutely didn't realize the scale of this situation. I was obviously wrong about using the online math tools, when in fact it's all about the SVG working draft. (You know those things about functions' order and such). Thank you.

Comment: I think I should shut up and read your answer carefully. You are are doing unnecessary checking/parsing strings, the `combineTranslates` function will only use clean objects, ready made, right now going to clean them up a little bit.

Comment: @thednp: Sounds like you did encounter [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/188688). Yesterday the missing ingredient for me was the fact that CSS has a different transformation origin by default, and that this was what made CSS and SVG more incompatible than they would seem at first glance. But the original question was far too narrowly scoped: it was about translate and skew, so it became confusing when your comments suddenly threw rotations into the mix. BTW: SVG 1.1 is a recommendation, not a working draft.

Comment: @thednp: As I said in chat, representing transformations as objects looses order, and it is my opinion that order of transformations is *very* important for transformations, to allow flexible designs. So while having things represented as an array of key-value objects (either `{‹key›:‹value›}` or `{key:"‹key›",value:‹value›}`) instead of a string would be beneficial, having them as an object feels like a huge restriction to me.

Comment: This answer is so valuable to me now, I finally understand it (after countless days of reading the draft and trying to implement it). It seems I have to do this calculation every frame of the animation, in that exact same order, it's slower than I wanted, but it's the only way to have it all consistently with the draft.

Answer (score 2):

Since your core question currently appears to be how to calculate that `d` distance. It comes from a talk where the skew operation is essentially described as (x, y) ↦ (x + d, y) for the case of `skewX`. If you look at [the SVG spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#EstablishingANewUserSpace) you will find a matrix which essentially says that the exact formula for `skewX(a)` is `(x, y) ↦ (x + cos(a) y, y)`. Likewise for `skewY(a)` you have `(x, y) ↦ (x, y + cos(a) x)`. So I'd say that `d := cos(a) * y` in the first case and `d := cos(a) * x` in the second case.

The question title suggested a different question to me, though. That question could be formulated as follows: given `transform="skewX(c) translate(a, b)"` for some numbers `a`, `b` and `c`, find `d` and `e` such that the transformation I just gave is the same as `translate(d, e) skewX(c)`. Or in other words: how do I have to change the entries of a `transform` if I want to move the transform to the outside of a `skewX`.

To find these numbers, look at the corresponding matrix products, as [defined in the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#EstablishingANewUserSpace):

```
⎡1 tan(c) 0⎤ ⎡1 0 a⎤   ⎡1  tan(c)  a + tan(c) b⎤   ⎡1 0 a + tan(c) b⎤ ⎡1 tan(c) 0⎤
⎢0   1    0⎥∙⎢0 1 b⎥ = ⎢0    1         b       ⎥ = ⎢0 1     b       ⎥∙⎢0   1    0⎥
⎣0   0    1⎦ ⎣0 0 1⎦   ⎣0    0         1       ⎦   ⎣0 0     1       ⎦ ⎣0   0    1⎦
```

So you'd have `d = a + tan(c) * b` and `e = b`. You simply apply the skew transformation to the translation vector. In other words:

```
skewX(c) translate(a, b) = translate(a + tan(c) * b, b) skewX(c)
```

You can do a similar computation for `y` and obtain:

```
skewY(c) translate(a, b) = translate(a, b + tan(c) * a) skewY(c)
```

If you have both `skewX` and `skewY` combined, you can move the `translate` out one step at a time, so that at each step you only have to deal with a single skew direction. If you want the opposite direction (i.e. move `translate` closer to the inside of a skew), use `- tan(c)` instead of `+ tan(c)` in these formulas.

Comment: I quit using matrix for now. As from what I understand atm, I can simply do `if ( skewX ) { translateX += tan(skewX) * translateY }` and similar for `skewY`, right?

Comment: @thednp: No, more like `translateX += tan(skewX) * translateY`.

Comment: Yes, I corrected my comment, but I think we need to do `translateX -= tan(skewX) * translateY` or we don't really compensate, we amplify the effect.

Comment: I tested the suggested code and it's not enough. It seems I also have to adjust the cx and cy, when rotation is used, if not, I will have to add a zero translation with the adjusted cx and cy. I will post an answer with sample code asap. But I will vote your answer up for the formula.

Comment: Your original question never said anything about rotation. And it was unclear from that question what you'd like to use the result for, so I'm unclear about the direction of the required compensation in your case. So perhaps you can edit the question to make it clearer what exactly you are looking for. Anyway, if rotations are involved, those are matrix multiplications as well. In general when moving a translation out one step, you apply the given transformation to the translation vector, when moving it in one step you apply the inverse. Except you never translate the translation vector.

Comment: Yes, seems I generally need 3 cases: 1: when translation is used, 2 when translation and rotation is used and 3 only when using skews.

Comment: How about `scale` or `matrix`? How about some of them being used multiple times, or in a different order? Most applications that I can think of would require being able to deal with these transformations one at a time, for whatever it is you want to compute (which I still don't know). Or to combine them all into a single `matrix` and then work with that.

Comment: It's also hard for me to explain everything, as changing the order of properties changes the render from slightly to chaotically, but I think I'm on the right track, I've learned that for SVGs, the transform's attribute order is: translate, scale, rotation, skews while for the transform CSS property it's translate, rotate, skews and scale. I am very greatful for your time and I thank you again for assisting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122085/discussion-between-mvg-and-thednp).